# Missing function in WinCE ASP server

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, windows-ce

I'm trying to go through an Html form to create a XML file. I'm trying to use this instruction to go through a HTML form until it finds a Button.

```
If instr(1,Request.Form.Key(x),"button") = 0 Then
```

But Request.Form.Key(x) isn't supported in WindowsCE ASP. Does anyone knows of any suitable replacement for this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WinCE there is no way to access the set of available keys in the collection.  The best you can do is have fore-knowledge of the likely and possible key names and try each in turn.  Yuck!

It would better if you removed the need for this approach altogether.